# Bixby oauth config file does not seem to work

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

Are there some examples of bixby app code implementing the oAuth using authorization.bxb file? I am trying to move our oAuth code from endpoints.bxb to authorization.bxb file as mentioned here https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/dev-guide/developers/actions.using-oauth#oauth-authorization since the former approach is being deprecated, but it seems like the app is now bypassing oAuth flow entirely.

Oauth based account linking has to be the first step in the app flow, so do I need to tag some/all endpoints in endpoints.bxb to trigger oAuth that is specified in authorization.bxb file?

Comment: Hi, when you say it is skipped, are you looking for specific logs? Did you print ```$vivContext``` to inspect if it contains ```accessToken```?

Answer (score 0):

Here are some update from bixby. Hope you will see some result out here.
https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/dev-guide/release-notes/sdk.2019-Q1-SDK-Release-Notes#19b-capsule-sdk-release-notes